# Sort array so that when concatenatenearby elements, we get max value

Tags: python, arrays

For example, input array:  `[4, 94, 9, 14, 1]` 
Need to sort array in that way so we get maximal value when concatenate nearby elements. Correct output: `[9, 94, 4, 14, 1]`,
so the max value is 9944141

Comment: afaik there is no way to solve this other than brute force (I really really tried to solve it smartly ... but there was a counter example to every single non-exaustive method I tried) ... apparently I like it looks like the dupe has a non-brute force method

Comment: Permutations, join, and sort?

Comment: Yep, then just need to map the `max` back to the sorted order .. ooh your comment went away. I guess there's an answer coming :)